# New files on host not showing on ubuntu (vmware)?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware, shared-folders

I have a host machine (Win7 64bit) running a VM with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I have set up the shared folder fine (although that was a headache in itself) and everything is working great. I use the Ubuntu machine as a PHP development server. If I edit the files on the host, they are changed on the guest and I can view the changes in a web browser connected to the guest. However, when I have been working on a site for a while, and I try to create a new empty file on the host the new file does not appear on the guest, and PHP includes for the file result in an error. I can then go into the guest and create a file with the exact same name successfully, despite it already existing on the host machine, and editing the file on the host does result in the changes being carried across.

File creation does not always fail to carry across to the guest, but it is annoying when it does. Any ideas why this would occur?

TL;DR: Files created on host machine are not propagating to guest machine through shared folders.